# Why we need to specify all dependencies (including transitives) in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

For example, my project depends on crate `A`, `A` depends on `B`, then my project can't use crate `B` until I put `B` in the dependencies section of my project's `Cargo.toml`.

In Java if you're using Maven or Gradle, you can directly use B and don't need to declare it in the `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`. Why didn't cargo follow that path?

Comment: You declare what crates you want to use, and Cargo makes sure they are available. Crate A may stop depending on crate B, or upgrade to a different version of crate B, and none of these steps should automatically result in any changes for the version of B you are using.

Comment: Crate A may always choose to expose the version of B it's using by re-exporting it.

Comment: Because in Java transitive dependencies are automatically available, you get the problem known as [JAR Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) - you cannot have multiple versions of a library on the classpath because they will clash. Rust took another approach and so avoided a similar problem.

Comment: Awesome "JAR Hell" link @Jesper, thanks! Made me appreciate the path cargo took...

An amusing part of that: _if both versions are present on the classpath, the behavior will be unpredictable. first, because of shadowing, classes that exist in both versions will only be loaded from one of them. worse, if a class that exists in one but not the other is accessed, that class will be loaded as well. code calling into the library might hence find a mix of both versions_! Good luck Java fellows 

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason is semver compatibility.

For example, say your crate depends on **A** with version 1.0, which depends on **B** with version 1.0:

```py
your_crate  -->  A 1.0  -->  B 1.0
```

- Now, **B** publishes a new version 2.0 that is not compatible to version 1.0.
- **A** upgrades to **B** version 2.0 and publishes a *minor* version 1.1. This version is compatible with 1.0, even though its dependency is not.
- You upgrade to **A** version 1.1.

```py
your_crate  -->  A 1.1  -->  B 2.0
```

The problem is, if you were able to access dependencies transitively, your code would break, because **B** 2.0 is not compatible with **B** 1.0.

---

There are two solutions to this:

1. The maintainer of **A** can re-export everything in **B**:

   ```rust
   // crate a
   pub use b;
   ```

   Like in Java, this allows you to access items of the transitive dependency **B**:

   ```rust
   // your crate
   use a::b;
   ```

   However, this means that **A** can't release a minor version that includes a major version bump in **B**. So when **B** releases version 2.0, **A** also has to release a new major version.
2. You can depend on **B**, too. This means that Cargo will try to choose a version of **B** that satisfies the requirements of both **A** and your crate. If it isn't able to, several versions of **B** are included:

   ```py
   your_crate  -->  A 1.1  -->  B 2.0
               -->  B 1.0
   ```

Comment: Great example @Aloso, I haven't realized before that when A re-exports B, that is now part of its public interface! So it shouldn't release a minor version if ANY of its public interface changes, even external ones... It is a liability to re-export anything then! Thanks.